# How to distinguish different form inputs in React?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two form inputs that I want to have for name and email.

[image]

I'm following examples from the React docs (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), but I'm not sure how I can distinguish between the two different forms. When I type in the first or second form, the other form receives `this.state.value` as well.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: '',
    }
}

handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value,
    })
}

input() {
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
            <input type="email" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

I'm using ES6. Do I need some sort of `id` to distinguish between the two forms? I tried to have a different value in the constructor (i.e. `email = ''`) but it yielded the same results.

Comment: Both inputs both get their `value` from `this.state.value`, so they will always have the same contents.

Comment: Store the state corresponding to each `<input>` separately - how exactly you go about doing this is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    textValue: '',
    emailValue: ''
  }
}

handleTextChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    textValue: e.target.value
  })
}

handleEmailChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    emailValue: e.target.value
  })
}

input() {
  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.textValue} onChange={this.handleTextChange.bind(this)}/>
      <input type="email" value={this.state.emailValue} onChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)}/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should store email & value in separate states.

```
this.state = {
    text: '',
    email: ''
}
```

And you should change a bit `handleChange` method

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.type]: e.target.value,
  })
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 2):

Use a `id` for each `<input/>` and while saving it in the `state`, use the `id` as the `key` and the input value as the `value`.

**[Update]**

As mentioned in the comments below, I've added the ability to generate unique `id`s for each instances.

Hope this helps!

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.ids = {
        textInput: Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5),
        emailInput: Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5),
      }
      this.state = {}
  }

  handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({
          [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
      })
  }

  input() {
      return (
          <form>
              <input type="text" value={this.state[this.ids.textInput]} id={this.ids.textInput} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
              <input type="email" value={this.state[this.ids.emailInput]} id={this.ids.emailInput} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
          </form>
      )
  }
  
  render(){
    console.log(this.state)
    return this.input()
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Adding an `id` inside a component means that it is no longer reusable, as it is invalid to have multiple elements with the same ID on the page. Passing a unique string as an argument to the event handler is a better idea, for this reason.

Comment: `id` means a unique identifier. I can be any random string. I use [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/shortid) to generate this ids.

Comment: In your answer, the `id`s are not unique for multiple instances of your component. If you know a good way to ensure that they are, then I would suggest including it in your answer.

Comment: @TomFenech Updated.

Comment: @TomFenech Even without this unique ids, with multiple instances, my code will work because each instance is bound to a scope and the `id` is also bound to that scope. But, as per the definition of `id`, it shouldn't be used like this.

Comment: Your code will "work" but the resulting document will be invalid. Personally I think that there are better alternatives to using the `id` attribute but at at least your random numbers are pretty unlikely to collide now.

Comment: @TomFenech valid point. I think is better to use the 'data' attribute.. It will solve the problem.